# How are loess and locfit different?

Tags: r, loess

'loess' is implemented in R 'stats' package and 'locfit' in 'locfit' package. They are both nonparametric regression methods that uses local regression. What are the difference between two methods?

Comment: I don't think this is a kind of question suited for this site. If you have a specific programming question, feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the statistical methods involved, you're probably better off asking your question at [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this introduction](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leiten/Lehre/Material/GLM_0708/Tutorium/locfit.pdf) it would appear that locfit is a generalization of loess and in fact you can obtain a loess fit using locfit, but locfit also has additional options to fit more general models including logistic regression style fits and general density estimation.  It can also fit loess style models, but using a different weighting formula or even varying bandwidth.